# Creating sub-categories via php

Tags: php, categories

Can someone tell me what's wrong here? I'm trying to create a category and a sub-category via PHP.

My code is

```
wp_set_object_terms($postID, array($subCategory, $catgeory), 'category');
```

But that creates two categories on the same hirearchy level; my goal is a category with a sub-category.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) function to achive this. First create the parent category, then create a child category.

```
$parent = wp_insert_term(
    'Parent Category', // category name
    'category', // taxonomy
    array(
        'description' => 'Category description', // optional
        'slug' => 'parent-category', // optional
    )
);

wp_insert_term(
    'Child Category', // category name
    'category', // taxonomy
    array(
        'description' => 'Child category description', // optional
        'slug' => 'child-category', // optional
        'parent' => $parent['term_id'], // set it as a sub-category
    )
);
```

Comment: Your answer had errors in it. One was syntax (no comma after slug => parent-category line) and for some reason $parent['temr_id'] didnt work despite it looking correct in the codex...

But it DID lead me in the right direction and I eventually got it working, so thank you!

My solution (theres probably an easier/simpler way):

    $parent = wp_set_object_terms($postID, $city, 'category');
    $parentID = get_cat_id($parent);$child = wp_set_object_terms($postID, $eventType, 'category', array('slug' => $eventSlug, 'parent' => $parentID));

Answer (score 0):

Your answer had errors in it. One was syntax (no comma after slug => parent-category line) and for some reason $parent['temr_id'] didnt work despite it looking correct in the codex...

But it DID lead me in the right direction and I eventually got it working, so thank you!

My solution (theres probably an easier/simpler way):

```
$parentTitle = 'category name';
$parentSlug = str_replace(' ', '', $parentTitle);
$parent = wp_set_object_terms($postID, $parentTitle, 'category', array('slug' => $parentSlug));
$parentID = get_cat_id($parent);
$childTitle = 'category name';
$childSlug = str_replace(' ', '', $childTitle);
$child = wp_set_object_terms($postID, $childTitle, 'category', array('slug' => $childSlug, 'parent' => $parentID));
```

Again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!